# Match node with least direct relationship of same type

Tags: neo4j, cypher

To find the single least rated user I have

```
match (:User)-[r:RATED*0..1]->(n:User)
return n, max(size(r)) as rating_count order by rating_count limit 1
```

But I think their might be a better way?

As I suspect this will calculate the count of ratings for all users then sort all rows before throwing away all but the first result

Comment: Your query does NOT find the least-rated user. Given your query, `SIZE(r)` is number of relationships in each matching variable-length path of length 0 or 1, and so the size can only be 0 or 1. In fact, every `n` will always have a matching path of size 0 (since such a "path" consists of just `n` itself). So, `MAX(SIZE(r))` will be 1 if `n` has any ratings at all, and 0 if it has none.

Comment: Actually this does work as im already using it - the 0..1 constraint on variable-length paths just allows for no ratings to be included in the results (which are then filtered to the most ratings with return n, max(size(r))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately ordering results requires touching all results, no way to optimize that right now.

One way you can speed this up is to modify your MATCH so it uses the relationship degree, something that can be retrieved directly from the node rather than having to expand the relationships to other nodes (you'll have to omit the type of the node the relationship connects to, so this only works if only :Users can be the start node of :RATED relationships).

Try:

```
MATCH (n:User)
RETURN n, SIZE((n)<-[:RATED]-()) as rating_count
ORDER BY rating_count limit 1
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a section in the neo4j manual on relationship degree? I couldn't find it

Comment: Also why do I have to omit the type of the node the relationship connects to? is  SIZE((n)<-[:RATED]-(:User)) slower?

Comment: This kind of improvement isn't well documented in the developers manual, though there is a [knowledge base entry](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/how-do-i-improve-the-performance-of-counting-number-of-relationships-on-a-node/) for this. And the reason we need to omit the label of the connecting node is that the only way to know the label of that node and filter accordingly is to expand the relationships to the other nodes and filter. Getting the degree of a relationship type doesn't require this, the starting node has all the data you need.

Answer (score 1):

One other thing to possibly consider would be multiple users with the same low rating. What if, for instance, there were ten users that all had no `:RATED` relationship at all? Would you only want to return a single one or would you prefer to know about all ten?

Building on InverseFalcon's solution you could add a few more lines to sort the results and make sure that all of the users who have the lowest ratings are included in your result.

```
MATCH (n:User)
WITH n, size((n)<-[:RATED]-()) AS rating
ORDER BY rating
WITH COLLECT([n,rating]) as users, MIN(rating) AS min_rating
RETURN [ r IN users WHERE r[1] = min_rating | r[0] ] AS min_rated_users, min_rating
```

Comment: Actually this is exactly what I did need but I came up with this (feedback appreciated):
MATCH (them:User)
//find out the lowest number of rating for any one of them
WITH them, min(size((them)<-[:RATED]-(:User))) as min_rating_count
//get all of them who share this lowest number of ratings
WITH them WHERE size((them)<-[:RATED]-(:User)) = min_rating_count
RETURN them